# Почему не происходит апдейт базы при post запросе?

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите разобраться. Смыcл такой: в базе nfs в таблице eroddondon есть 3 поля: id, title и content.
Есть форма сохранения (обновления) данных в таблице, но она почему-то не сохраняет данные(запрос посылается и к БД актуальное подключение). Но обновить (отредактировать, изменить, сохранить) данные, посылаемые POSTом, нужно по запросу, только в колонке с id, равным 1.

Сам код (но не работает почему-то...):

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="test";
    $db_name="nfs";
    $link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$sql = ("UPDATE eroddondon SET title='".$_POST["title"]."', content='".$_POST["content"]."' WHERE id=1");

    if ($sql) {
        echo "<p>Обновлено!</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Ошибка!</p>";
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="title" value="title">
<input type="text" name="content" value="content">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: @dimkachel, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 8):

[[@dimkachel](/users/23613/dimkachel)](/users/23613/dimkachel), Вот хотите верьте, а хотите нет, но с начала этого месяца я третий раз вижу подобное. И везед одно и то же - строка запроса присваивается переменной, но сам запрос не выполняется. Самое главное, что все искренне удивляются, почему результат нулевой. Где у вас [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php)? И перейдя по ссылке, не забудьте прочитать выделенное красным цветом.

P.S. Откройте тайну, где вы это взяли? У какого очередного "гуру"?